# How to format bullets on Excel to Powerpoint VBA so that bullets appear ONLY before pharagraphs

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Im writing a VBA code to start and create a Power Point Presentation from Excel VBA.

The thing is, I add a Textbox to some slides with a text that comes from excel, and I have configured it to have Bullets. But my problem is that the code sets the bullets to be in all of the lines of the textbox, even when there is a blank space between pharagraphs. How do I set the bullets to appear only before texts, and not in the blank spaces?

The code i am using is:

```
Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(10, ppLayoutCustom)
SlideTitle = "Noticias Relevantes"
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = SlideTitle
pptSlide.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 22

Set pptTextbox = pptSlide.Shapes(1)

pptTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PPT").Range("B143").Value
pptTextbox.Top = 83
pptTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignJustify
```

pd: The ppt looks like this:
[ImagePPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMsZA.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you call blank spaces are actually paragraphs. So when you apply bullets to the entire text frame **all** the paragraphs, even those without any text, get bullets.

To solve this you need to loop through the paragraphs in the TextRange and test the length of the text. Then you can apply the bullets to the paragraphs that have text.

Comment: thanks! could you tell me which function or code would you use for this? (for example, .LoopThrough or something like that) im new in VBA so i dont know all of the codes. Also, i changed my code so that instead of creating a new textbox, i insert the text in the text frame that comes with the custom slide layout (im not using the Title Only layout anymore) but i am still having the bullets problem. Thanks! I edited the code to the new one